# No matching point found between 2 collections of System.Windows.Points

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, double

I have a function where I try to find a matching Point between 2 collections of 4 Points each, but *sometimes* the function reports the collections do not share a common Point even though in the debugger I see they do. is the debugger not showing me the full precision of the points so I do not see the difference? or is there something else going on here? here's the code to blame:

```
public static Point CorrectForAllowedDrawArea(Point previousDisplayLocation, Point newDisplayLocation, Rect displayLimitedArea, Rect newBoundingBox)
{
    // get area that encloses both rectangles
    Rect enclosingRect = Rect.Union(displayLimitedArea, newBoundingBox);
    // get corners of outer rectangle, index matters for getting opposite corner
    var outsideCorners = new[] { enclosingRect.TopLeft, enclosingRect.TopRight, enclosingRect.BottomRight, enclosingRect.BottomLeft }.ToList();
    // get corners of inner rectangle
    var insideCorners = new[] { displayLimitedArea.TopLeft, displayLimitedArea.TopRight, displayLimitedArea.BottomRight, displayLimitedArea.BottomLeft }.ToList();
    // get the first found corner that both rectangles share
    Point sharedCorner = outsideCorners.FirstOrDefault((corner) => insideCorners.Contains(corner));
    // find the index of the opposite corner
    int oppositeCornerIndex = (outsideCorners.IndexOf(sharedCorner) + 2) % 4;
```

on the last line 'sharedCorner' is sometimes set to default(Point) even though both Point collections appear to share 1 Point.

**EDIT:** I should mention if I place the debugger back to the top of the function and restart it still does not find the matching point. I should also mention that this function uses the Point class of the System.Windows namespace and *not* of the System.Drawing namespace! Thanks for pointing this out to me in the comments.

Comment: Somewhere you are relying on Equals() for double or float here. And that will fail when there are rounding errors.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I suspected that too, but it seems only integers are used given `Point` and not `PointF`.

Comment: @Leppie: right, if this is from System.Drawing. Not definitively clear from the question. Note "the full precision of the points"

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We really need to see what the definition of `insideCorners.Contains(corner)` is, but I suspect that your problem is due to the inherent inaccuracies with floating point numbers.

You cannot compare two floating point values like this:

```
if (a == b)
{
    // Values are equal
}
```

especially if either `a` or `b` are calculated values.

You'll need to implement something along the lines of:

```
if (Math.Abs(a - b) < some_small_value)
{
    // Values are equal
}
```

Comment: you're right, I changed it to Point sharedCorner = outsideCorners.FirstOrDefault((outsideCorner) => insideCorners.Exists((insideCorner) => Math.Abs((insideCorner - outsideCorner).Length) < Math.Pow(10, -10))); which checks for equality using a tolerance treshold and it works but it's also very slow, thanks for pointing me in this direction